# print three pictures + text then a new row in PHP

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-5

I am trying to create a news site, where 3 articles (image, date, text) per row are displayed. After that a new should begin.

The code produces the articles as I want them put not the three per row printing. The first row has two articles and the rest just one.

```
<?php
    //get all the pictures and texts
    $pictures = glob('uploads/news/pictures/*');
    $texts = glob('uploads/news/text/*');

    if(!$pictures || !$texts){
        $error_msg = 'Es gibt keine News';
        echo '<h2 class="mt-2 mb-3 text-white center">'.$error_msg.'</h2>';
        return;
    }

    //sort the pictures and texts by date
    array_multisort(array_map('filemtime', $pictures), SORT_NUMERIC, SORT_DESC, $pictures);
    array_multisort(array_map('filemtime', $texts), SORT_NUMERIC, SORT_DESC, $texts);

    //display one picture with its text and the date within a box, 3 boxes per row
    echo '<div class="container">';
    $count = 1;
    for($i = 0; $i < count($pictures); $i++){
        if($count % 3 == 1){
            echo '<div class="row">';
        }
        echo '<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 p-3 border rounded shadow-lg mx-3">';
        echo '<div class="text-center">';
        echo '<img src="'.$pictures[$i].'" class="img-responsive" alt="News Image">';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<p class="mt-2 mb-3 form-text text-white">'.date('Y-m-d', filemtime($pictures[$i])).'</p>';
        echo '<br>';
        echo '<p class="mt-2 mb-3 form-text text-white">'.file_get_contents($texts[$i]).'</p>';
        echo '</div>';
        if(($count)%3 == 0){
            echo '</div>';
        }
        $count++;
    }
    echo '</div>';
?>
```

Comment: I can't make sense of this. _"where 3 articles (image, date, text) per row are displayed"_ - yes, but you create all three of those at once - in one and the same loop iteration. So why does wrapping them in a row div depend on your counter to begin with?

Comment: That was the only way i achieve any displaying right next to each other. All other trys resulted in a one article per row result

Comment: Putting this into a `col-xy-4` element should automatically make three articles appear next to each other in a row. And you don't need to "close" a row either - you can have more than three `col-xy-4` items in a row, they will automatically break into multiple rows. Try what happens when you open and close the row element outside of your loop, and inside create the `col-xy-4` element containing the article only.

Comment: I opend and closed the row outside the loop and gave the parameter to the div-s within. This results in one article taking the width of the whole row. Did i do it wrong?

 e.g. echo '<div class=" col-xy-4 p-3 border rounded shadow-lg mx-3">';

Comment: `mx-3` adds _margin_, which is not something you should do on columns, I think. Please try with nothing but the actual column classes first, you can fix other minor display issues such as spacing later.

Comment: The "text" of your articles, is that _pure_ text? Or does it perhaps contain HTML code? HTML code maybe, that might not be allowed in a `p` element to begin with? (And would therefor make the browser "correct" by closing the `p` element earlier than you think, which could mess up the whole structure.)